# Keras LSTM RNN for Classification

Tags: keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

Can an LSTM “count” the number of times a sensor hit a peak reading?

I created a simple example in which 2 machines fail as soon as they receive their third sensor rating of 25pts or higher. However, after hours of trying differing LSTM models in keras, all my models want to categorize all my samples as all true, or all false.

Can anyone point me in the right direction for detecting a rule like this?

It’s 2 machines with about 20ish time stamps and only 2 sensors (X1, X2).

[My data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQrEj.png)

Sequence Length = 10 time steps
This gives 23 “windows” or samples, each of of which is 10 time steps long.

The Confusion Matrix always ends up as:

array([[ 0, 15],
       [ 0,  8]])

The Y is simply a “getting close to failure” subjective measurement that I saw other preventative maintenance examples use, with great results. I should be able to get 100% accuracy given I imposed my own rule here.

---

Here is one version of my model, but regardless of layers or neurons or epochs, I get all true or all false. I also tried with just 1 LSTM instead of 2. Same results.

```
nb_features = seq_array.shape[2] #this is 2
nb_out = label_array.shape[1]  #this is 1

model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(
     input_shape=(sequence_length, nb_features),
     units=20,
     return_sequences=True))

model.add(LSTM(
units=10,
     return_sequences=False))

model.add(Dense(units=20,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(units=20,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(units=10,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(units=1,activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=    ['accuracy'])
```

The data file is here ---> https://github.com/dclengacher/test-repo/blob/master/ten_machines.csv

Comment: Sorry, but what is your aim?
If you know that a machine might fail after 3 events, you can just keep track of that.
Using LSTM is an overkill

Comment: The row that’s missing in both examples is the time step in which the machine failed.  This is a hypothetical with applications beyond preventative maintenance. It’s also similar to other Prev Maintanence data sets and models I’ve seen on Git.  However, I’m making up a different rule that caused failure and trying to detect it. If I can do that....then I will know the whether or not RNN LSTM can detect that type of complexity.

Comment: Try changing the last activation function to sigmoid